# Hadrons as partons? e.g. hadron distribution function inside another hadron

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, pions, lattice-gauge-theory

Parton distribution functions (PDFs) are typically seen as describing the probability that a parton, e.g. a quark or gluon, can be found in a hadron with particular momentum fraction $x$. They can be expressed in terms of matrix elements of a light-cone-seperated bilocal operator. For example, the PDF of a quark $q$ inside a hadron state $H$ (e.g. a proton) with momentum $P$ and polarization $\lambda$ is given by

$$q_{H}\left(x,\mu^2\right) = \int\frac{dz_-}{4\pi}e^{ixz_-P^+}\langle P,\lambda|\bar{q}(z_-)\gamma^+W(z_-,0)q(0)|P,\lambda\rangle$$

here $W(z_-,0)$ is a Wilson line connecting $0$ and $z_-$ in a straight line along the $z_-$ lightcone direction, providing gauge invariance to the matrix element.

Relatedly, the gluon distribution function in the same hadron would be

$$g_{H}\left(x,\mu^2\right) = \int\frac{dz_-}{2\pi x P^+}e^{ixz_-P^+}\langle P,\lambda|F^{\mu +}(z_-)W(z_-,0)F^{+}_{\mu}(0)|P,\lambda\rangle$$

I'm curious about whether one could reasonably define and calculate a "parton" distribution function but where the parton is a known composite particle. For example, suppose we could construct a pion field $\pi^i (x)$. Then maybe one could calculate a distribution function for the pion within the proton as

$$f_{\pi/H}\left(x,\mu^2\right) = \int\frac{dz_-}{2\pi} e^{ixz_-P^+}\langle P,\lambda|\pi^i(z_-)^{\dagger}i \overleftrightarrow{\partial}\pi^i(0)|P,\lambda\rangle$$

The above formula is just a guess for what a PDF of a (color neutral) pion inside a proton might be.

**Question:** Do such functions exist? If so, have they been studied?

My motivation for considering this is partially esoteric, but also partially based on nuclear physics. Some nuclei are well described by bound states of $\alpha$-particles and nucleons, giving rise to [the concept of $\alpha$-clustering](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0954-3899/43/2/024003#:%7E:text=In%20many%20light%20alpha%2Dconjugate,building%20blocks%20of%20alpha%20particles.). For such nuclei, it may be more relevant to ask for the "$\alpha$-particle distribution function". By extension, maybe certain hadrons could be better described by "hadron distribution functions" rather than parton (quark & gluon) distribution functions.

One obvious hurdle to this entire concept is that we don't know how to construct a hadron field out of QCD. For example, for the pion, we only know the interpolating current $J^a (x)=i \bar q (x) \gamma^5 T^a q(x)$ which annihilates an asymptotic pion state.

$$\langle 0 | J^a (x) |\pi^b (p)\rangle \sim \delta^{ab} e^{-ipx}$$

but this does not quite imply a relation like $J^a(x) = \pi^a (x)$. Maybe one could just calculate a "pion distribution function within a proton" using $J^a(x)$ and just see what happens? I'm not sure...

Comment: In the most recent Phenomenology conference I attended I saw slides defining the W boson as a parton to nucleons (although not exactly similar to your case it's related). I'm guessing you can define this as you please provided it makes sense.

Comment: @Triatticus The $W$-bosons are fundamental (UV) degrees of freedom (DOF) in the full theory (standard model). Defining parton distribution functions for any fundamental DOF of the standard model is straightforward, since the exact field operators are known (e.g. any lepton PDF would be written in the exact same way as a quark PDF). I'm curious about composite particles which are not themselves fundamental DOF, but are effective, infrared DOF.

Comment: There is a strange planet of the [chiral bag model](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0370-1573(96)00013-0), thought to live in the thin shell between the chiral symmetry breaking and the confinement scale, one slightly smaller than the other. It is an effective theory of **constituent**, not current, quarks and pions, i.e. a bit of a σ model before complete hadronization. People have made connections to the Skyrme planets too...

Comment: @ArturodonJuan hence why I said related